# pandas dataframe. сравнить значения датафреймов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

У меня есть несколько датафреймов df, df_left_border, df_right_border, где
df [image: это df]

df_left_border

[image: это df_left_border]

df_right_border аналогичен left

Необходимо посчитать количество элементов df, которые больше соответствующего значения df_left.. и меньше соответствующего значения df_right.. То есть как то сравнить все значения первой строки df со значениями первой строки двух других датафреймов, все значения второй строки со значениями второй строки двух других датафреймов и тд.

Можно ли это сделать без больших затрат времени, без вложенных циклов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью метода [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) можно применять пользовательские функции к фрейму вдоль заданной оси (нас интересует сравнение значений каждого фрейма построчно, значит функцию применять мы тоже хотим построчно, в пандасе это ось 1).

Функция, переданная в `apply`, принимает в качестве аргумента объект `pandas.Series`, содержащий данные текущей строке (в случае с осью 1). Поле `.name` у этого `Series` содержит индекс текущей строки, по этому индексу мы можем получить соответствующие верхнюю и нижнюю границы из `df_left` и `df_right`, а затем сравнить  значения массива в текущей строке `df` с этими границами. В случае если значения-массивы в `df` это `numpy.ndarray`, то код применяемой к фрейму функции может быть следующим:

```py
def fn(row):
    current_row_index = row.name
    current_row_values = row["BODY_AVG_VALUE"]

    lower_bound = df_left_border.loc[current_row_index, "BODY_AVG_VALUE"]
    upper_bound = df_right_border.loc[current_row_index, "BODY_AVG_VALUE"]

    satisfy_lower_bound = current_row_values >= lower_bound
    satisfy_upper_bound = current_row_values <= upper_bound

    return np.logical_and(satisfy_lower_bound, satisfy_upper_bound).sum()


result = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

Если тип массивов в `df` неизвестен, то можно заменить последние 3 строчки `fn` на более общий случий:

```
    return len(
        [val for val in current_row_values if val >= lower_bound and val <= upper_bound]
    )
```